# How use minitest/mock for stub calls with expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, minitest

See example. Its not real code but show the problem.
In code generator calls twice with other args. I want to check one call with arg install is called, and stub other calls

```
def test
  bundle_command_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
  bundle_command_mock.expect(:call, nil, ['install'])
  generator.stub(:bundle_command, bundle_command_mock) do |g|
    g.bundle_command('install')
    g.bundle_command('exec spring binstub --all') # <-- This call raise error No more expects available for :call: ["exec spring binstub --all"]
  end

  bundle_command_mock.verify
end
```

Its posible? I know thats posible in mocha. See work example in mocha

```
def test
  generator.expects(:bundle_command).with('install').once
  generator.stubs(:bundle_command).with('exec spring binstub --all')

  generator.bundle_command("install")
  generator.bundle_command("exec spring binstub --all")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Stubbed value is working just within the block so you probably should:

```
def test
  bundle_command_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
  bundle_command_mock.expect(:call, nil, ['install'])
  generator.stub(:bundle_command, bundle_command_mock) do |g|
    g.bundle_command('install')
    g.bundle_command('exec spring binstub --all') # <-- This call raise error No more expects available for :call: ["exec spring binstub --all"]
  end

  bundle_command_mock.verify
end
```